# Matrix computation without explicit inversions

Tags: matrices

[image]

So far all I have figured out is for part b, I need to implement it using the fact that A^-6 = (A^-1)^6. Any help or guidance is highly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Solve the system $A^6y=x$ for $y$ using e.g. Gauss Jordan.

Comment: Part (a) is only a little more complicated: put $y=(C^{-1}+A)x$, and solve for $y$ in $Cy=(I+CA)x$, using Gauss-Jordan elimination as @Math1000 says. Then solve for $z$ in $Bz=(2A+I)y$.

Comment: As for your final paragraph: you are explicitly inverting $A$, which is not allowed. (And I assume that explicitly inverting $A^6$ is also forbidden, before you get any ideas.)